# Unable to mount SD card to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, linux, mount

Can anybody explain how to mount ICS/Jellybean on Ubuntu 12.04 without rooting? When I connect my phone, it goes into charging mode, however, I can't mount the phone memory/sdcard to my Ubuntu system. On Windows virtual machine, it works just fine! Please help!

Comment: If it's using MTP, then there are a number of questions you may want to look at. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/better-way-to-connect-galaxy-nexus-ics-to-linux, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34162/what-are-my-options-for-connecting-my-android-to-ubuntu, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52072/how-do-i-make-my-linux-pc-mount-my-android-4-2-2-phone-using-mtp

Comment: Use go-mtpfs. See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/62661/50997 for instructions.